# Is there "return false;" code for an "if" statement that is not located in a function?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a class assignment and we are learning if/else statements. I would like to know if there is code similar to `return false;` for an `if` statement.

For example:

```
var why = prompt("Why won't you fill in my prompt?");

if(why === "" || why === null){
   // How can you make this false, so that it will ask the prompt question again?
   return false; /*Like that--but not a function*/
}
```

Comment: What do you want `return false;` to do? Normally, `return false` will cause the interpreter to jump to another place in the code. Where should it jump in this case?

Comment: `while (!why) { why = prompt("Why won't you fill in my prompt?"); }` or even better with do { } while(expression); [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/22VU8/)

Comment: No, because there's no point to returning false outside a function. What do you want to accomplish exactly?

Comment: You can use a while loop if you need to keep asking until you get a response. Also, you don't need "===" because you are comparing strings, not objects. Just use "==".

Comment: I just want to ask the prompt question again if the initial prompt was left empty. I also do not want it to continue to the next line of code until the person fills in the prompt. We have not learned functions yet, and can only use an if statement to validate the prompt. I was just wondering if there is code to add to the if statement to make it jump back up to ask the prompt question again.

Answer (score 1):

Define a container for your response first and prompt until it's an acceptable value:

```
var reason = null;

while (reason === "" || reason === null) {
  reason = prompt("Why won't you fill in my prompt?");
}

// continue with the reason defined
```

Comment: @NiklasB. I'd have to check for `null` anyway, as hitting `Escape` will yield `null`. And that one check won't hurt, but it's imho quite readable.

Comment: @NiklasB. One could avoid checking for null when coercing the value to a String with an or: `while ((reason || "") === "")`, but that does not improve readability much.

Comment: Why not simply use `while(!reason)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   var why=null; 

   while (why===null||why===""){
        why = prompt("Why won't you fill in my prompt?");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only use an if statement. This is our second week of Javascript, and they only want us to use what we have learned to this point, or we will receive an 0. I just wanted to know if it is possible to return back to the prompt somehow. The teachers don't care that you can click ok, ok, ok, ok and come up with an answer, but I do.

Comment: with no looping there's no way you can do that other than making a massive nested if statement:
`why=prompt(blahblah); if (why===null) {why=prompt(blahblah) if (why===null) { etc...`

Comment: Thanks, Snowburnt. That's all I needed to know.